# Mandar un array desde Python a PHP

Tags: php, python, array, wsdl

Estoy tratando de consumir con Python un WSDL creado en PHP.
Fragmento del Servicio:

```
<?php
    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    function Suma ($numbers){
        return array_sum($numbers);
    }
    ...
```

Cliente:

```
from suds.client import Client

def wsarchivo():
    url = "http://localhost/PracticaSumaArray/server.php?wsdl"
    client = Client(url)
    res = client.service.Suma([1,2,3])
    print(res)

wsarchivo()
```

Pero al momento de correrlo no funciona el mandar el parámetro de esta manera, a diferencia de hacerlo con un cliente en PHP que la forma de enviar el parámetro seria `'numbers' => array(1, 2, 3)` y funciona correctamente.

Comment: en el contrato wsdl esta la funcion suma y este indica que puedes pasarle un array como parametro?

Comment: De hecho lo tengo definido como xsd:int, cual sería el equivalente para un array?

Comment: quizas pueda ayudar la documentacion https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383522. Ahora bien, por que tomar la desicion de realizar un servicio soap y no un api rest? (solo de curioso)

Comment: Ah esto solo es por un curso de la escuela, yo tambien preferiría api rest

Comment: podrias, ya que el arametro esta definido como un entero y no como un array enviarle un numero, obviamnete PHP dara un error por que espera un array, pero comprueba primeramente que el parametro este llegando a PHP, si todo funciona bien el problema esta en la definicion del parametro que se espera en el contrato wsdl. API REST es el presente y hasta casi el pasado...

Comment: Lo raro es que al mandarle un array desde un cliente en PHP funciona correctamente, y si de hecho lo probé mandandole un entero desde Python y también funcionó bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude resolver mi problema, lo dejo aquí por si a alguien más le sirve, el primer error que cometí fue el de declarar el parámetro de entrada como entero `xsd:int`, entonces lo que hice fue declararlo como `SOAP-ENC:Array` en el server en PHP:

```
$server->register(
        'Suma',
        array('numbers' => 'SOAP-ENC:Array'),
        array('return' => 'xsd:int'),
        $ns
    );
```

Ahora en el cliente en Python utilicé el metodo `factory.create()` del cliente de suds para declarar una variable con el tipo `SOAP-ENC:Array`

```
from suds.client import Client

def wsarchivo():
    client = Client("http://localhost/PracticaSumaArray/server.php?wsdl")
    request = client.factory.create('SOAP-ENC:Array')
    request.numbers = [1,2,3]
    res = client.service.Suma(request)
    print(res)

wsarchivo()
```

Al ejecutar:

```
Salida:
6
```